# Duplicates in Devexpress ASPxCallback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, devexpress

I have a `ASPxCallback` with a strange behavior, when there is connection problem (>30 seconds without connection and < 1 min) that starts just few millisecond after a callback's start, this callback remains in a pending state and after exactly 8.3 minutes I receive the event callback complete, but the callback is executed twice.

My callback is placed inside the click event (javascript on client) of a button and the page is loaded inside a iframe, the code appear as below :

```
     MyCallback.PerformCallback ( Math.round(Math.random()*10000) );
```

the line above is the only `PerformCallBack` over object `MyCallback`, button's postback is disabled and the break point over `PerformCallback` fired only one times.

In the codebheind there is these lines :

```
 protected void MyCallBack_Callback(object source, DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallback.CallbackEventArgs e)
 {
        lock (this)
        {
             Response.AppendToLog("Operation done with ID : " + e.Parameter );
        }
 }
```

The IIS log file contains these lines :

`2014-06-18 09:11:41 xxx.yyy.zzz.www POST /Container.aspx CdlID=XYZ&ID=0&NumOfPage=1Operation+done+with+ID+:+5510 82 - xxx.yyy.zzz.www Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 200 0 1236 18501
2014-06-18 09:19:40 xxx.yyy.zzz.www POST /Container.aspx CdlID=XYZ&ID=0&NumOfPage=1Operation+done+with+ID+:+5510 82 - xxx.yyy.zzz.www Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 1544`

as you can see the call appear to be duplicated.

This is the network log seen by the client (using chrome)
[image: red line over 8.3 min waiting]

Now I am interested in understand the reason of this problem.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Can you post the javascript.  I'm wondering if it is something that might propagating or a default action.

Comment: here my clientside code 
http://pastebin.com/zsyziUTw